# Child table doesn't receive data from parent in phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm fairly new to phpMyAdmin, and I've come across a problem...

I have two tables in my database, `Parent` and `Child`. Both have an ID and username field, and I've set up the foreign key in working order (e.g. if I change the `Parent.id`, the `Child.id` get changed aswell.

However, I wish the Child table would automatically create a new record for each new entry made in the parent. So if I create a new `Parent.id`, `Child` should display the newly created `Parent.id`.

Example when I insert into Parent a new username, it'll get ID of 1 and username 'Daniel'.
I want child to have these values aswell in `Child.id` and `Child.username` respectively, so Child gets filled with 1, 'Daniel' aswell.

As for now, Child remains empty with every record I insert into Parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a 1:1 relationship between parent and child? (Typically we use the terms 'parent' and 'child' to refer to two sides of a 1:M relationship, so that is a little confusing.)

Have you considered a trigger? The trigger would update the child the way you want, each time you do something to the parent. Here is the description of [how to add a trigger to an insert command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) in MySQL.

Comment: I'm not familiar with those triggers, but thanks for pointing out! I've created databases before with SQL server management studio, and once I'd set up the constraints properly, the database would fill all related fields in other tables automatically. phpMyAdmin doesn't seem to do that...

Comment: The trigger thing looks like an awful lot of work for something that should be relatively simple. It's almost easier to just put all columns in one table =/

Comment: Yes, for one:one relationships, everything CAN go in one table. That's why I asked! :)